# Viewset 'create' custom assign value in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework

Would like to set a *CustomUser*'s username by using the input email, but where to do the custom assigning, in view? At the same time it receiving a file as well.

**Models.py**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    avatar = models.ImageField(max_length=None, upload_to='avatar', blank=True)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'avatar', 'groups')
```

**Views.py**

```
class CustomUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: It should be related to django models, where you can populate the **username** with model's **save** method, or using **pre_save** and/or **post_save** signals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What @Anzel said would work but if you want to do it in **django-rest-framework** you could override the `create` method of your `CustomUserSerializer`. Like:

```
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    groups = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(
            username    =validated_data['email'], # HERE
            email       =validated_data['email'],
            password    =validated_data['password'],
            first_name  =validated_data['first_name'], 
            last_name   =validated_data['last_name'],
            avatar      =validated_data['avatar'],
        )

        user.groups = validated_data['groups']
        return user

    class Meta:
       model = CustomUser
       fields = (
           'id', 
           'first_name', 
           'last_name', 
           'email', 
           'password', 
           'avatar', 
           'groups'
       )
```

Comment: One question, so if I got a field "groups", how should I assign in create method? cause when i assign as "groups =validated_data['groups']", it give me an error

Comment: @CYChong, how do you POST group? Do you include group's `id` in request?

Comment: yes, i include group id in the request (the serializer I added a 'groups' field), which using the default groups by the UserModel

Comment: @CYChong, Single group or multiple groups?

Comment: can multi-selection (multiple-groups)