# django rest framework create user with password

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Using django-rest-framework 3 and django 1.8

I am trying to create a user using django-rest-framework ModelViewSerializer. problem is that the default objects.create method used by DRF leave the password as plain text.

The problem is that DRF serialzer create method is using `objects.create` [querysets/#create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#create) method instead of using `objects.create_user` method.

code from [serializers.py](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py) line 775

```
instance = ModelClass.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

What is the best solution for this? i can override the serializer.create method to use objects.user_create instead of objects.create but it does not feel like the right solution.

rest of code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import viewsets

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email','password')
        write_only_fields = ('password',)


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):   
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer = UserSerializer()
```

Comment: Why doesn't it seem right to you?  I think I would go that way. Searched a bit and at least found this SO post (different question), but overriding `create()` is used for that purpose in the accepted answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27763502/870769

Comment: The `write_only_fields` argument is not used anymore. Instead, `extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}` should be used in the Meta-class [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments)

Answer (score 22):

you can override `create` in UserSerializer:

```python
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # ....

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user
```

other solutions can be overriding `perform_create` in ViewSet class or you can write your own `create` method in your viewset class

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet): 
    def create(self, request, format=None):
        # create user here
        # do not call seriailzer.save()
```

**UPDATE:** after @freethebees commented, overriding `perform_create` also works, so here is the code snippet:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet, mixins.CreateModelMixin): 
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        # use User.objects.create_user to create user
        pass
```

**NOTE**:
this answer gives 3 solutions, choose the one you think it better fits your needs and your project's ecosystem

**NOTE 2**
I personally prefer overriding `create` in `UserViewSet` (second code snippet) because there you can simply return your custom `Response` (for example return user profile after login)

Comment: Why would you recommend overriding the `create` method in a serialiser rather than `perform_create` in a ViewSet?

Comment: @freethebees it's an old answer, I don't remember why :-), but you are right `perform_create` seems to be cleaner solution, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Oh I wasn't suggesting either way was better. I was just interested. I haven't seen where either method would be the clear choice.

Comment: Instead of using `User.objects.create_user`, could you just use the `make_password` function from `django.contrib.auth.hashers`? So, inside of `perform_create` you would have two lines: `serializer.validated_data['password'] = make_password(serializer.validated_data['password'])` and `serializer.save()`

Comment: @Nick for your solution I think you only need to update `validate_password` in serializer and it should work. (but I personally don't like it, 1. using `create_user` is recommended in django docs (think about custom user models and you should do all `create_user` stuffs in your serializer, update same code in 2 places) 2. I prefer explicit solution (i think your solution makes code a little harder to understand))

Answer (score 11):

In addition to @aliva's answer where you miss out on the functionalities in `serializers.Modelserializer.create()` (which could be quite nice to preserve, for example handling of many-to-many relations), there is a way to keep this.

By using the `user.set_password()` method, the password can also be correctly set, like:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = super().create(validated_data)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

This has the benefit of keeping the super class' functionality, but the downside of an additional write to the database. Decide which trade-off is more important to you :-).

See documentation for [set_password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser).

Comment: This worked for me! I can't understand why other suggested approaches to this question did not work.

Comment: The reason no one else has suggested this, is that it will save the raw user password to the database which is a huge anti-pattern. Even if it lives in the database for only 1ms, it could live in logs forever.

Comment: @jkatzer : set_password() hashes the password. Is it still a problem?

Comment: @Aurélien True, here's the documentation which confirms this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser

Comment: @Erikw Indeed, I was aware of this, so this is not a n "anti-pattern"  practice, isn't it?

Answer (score 9):

There is even better option to validate password in serializer

```py
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def validate_password(self, value: str) -> str:
        return make_password(value)
```

Comment: This has the added benefit of also applying to updates, if that's something your view supports.

Comment: `return validate_password(value)` works better here, Django 3.2.2

Comment: The value of validated_data['password'] in serializer.create method has the same old value, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3):

A complete example that support `POST` and `PUT`/`PATCH` without another SQL UPDATE statement.

```
class MyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        if "password" in validated_data:
            from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
            validated_data["password"] = make_password(validated_data["password"])
        return super().create(validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        if "password" in validated_data:
            from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
            validated_data["password"] = make_password(validated_data["password"])
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

Comment: Great, thank you. After searching for ages I didn't realise that Django was hashing passwords causing all my sign in attempts to fail.