# How to create a User model object using Django REST framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using the shell to make this happen:

```
serializer = UserSerializer(data={'first_name':'brody', 'username':'brodyboy'})
serializer.is_valid() // returns True
serializer.save() // I save it, assuming it should create a new User object.
```

When I check to see the `User` objects I've made:

```
User.objects.all() // <QuerySet [ ]>  -- returns nothing.
```

models.py:

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)      
    username = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=20)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=19)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

Serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ('first_name', 'username')

   def create(self, validated_data):
      return User.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

EDIT: *not a duplicate so cash me ousside how bow dah*

UPDATE: all I had to do was remove the `create` method. For some reason having that method prevented me from saving my User object to the database.

Comment: What does `serializer.save()` returns ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django rest framework create user with password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746584/django-rest-framework-create-user-with-password)

Comment: @dnit13 it returns `<User: brodyboy>`, which I find strange because shouldn't that object be added to the User database, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the `create` method and now I'm able to add Users to my database.